# Shortcode for Python Flask

Tags: python, html, flask, shortcode, mailer

I'm building an emailer system where the user uploads a CSV containing the headers such as email, name, company name. The rows contain all the informations of different companies.

The program then loops through the rows of the CSV and sends it out to the email contained in the CSV.

I want to implement a shortcode system, similar to that of WordPress's.

This is how the python script will interpret the shortcodes:

```
Name: [Name]
Subject: Proposal for [company-name]

Message:
Dear [name],
...
...
```

The program should dynamically load the CSV and interpret the shortcodes from the CSV.

I need some advice on how to go about doing this. Thank you!

Comment: What's your **specific** question?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure why string formatting doesn't solve this problem directly, but if you want complex HTML in your email, or are thinking about abstracting the templates away from being hardcoded, I recommend not reinventing the wheel -- if you're using Python, I'd say just use Jinja2 templating mixed with CSV parsing to fill in the template

```
from __future__ import print_function
from jinja2 import Template
import csv
try:
  from StringIO import StringIO
except:
  from io import StringIO


templatestr = '''Name: {{name}}
Subject: Proposal for {{company_name}}

Message:
Dear {{name}},...
'''

rawcsv = StringIO('''nobody,company1
somebody,company2
''')

for row in csv.reader(rawcsv):
  print('~~~~~~~ {} ~~~~~~~~'.format(row))
  name, company_name = row
  result = Template(templatestr).render(name=name, company_name=company_name)
  print(result)
```

(edited to add CSV sample)